# Proper way of mapping in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that itself uses another third party WCF service. It's basically a proxy. So I'm getting a request to my own one and I have just to "forward" it to the third party one.

I would like then to map from my flattened request (that's the way it's been decided to be coded) to the slightly more complex request the other service needs.

Although quite a few of the properties in each request are a naming match my issues are the following

1. There are properties flattened in my request in relation to theirs
2. There's a huge load of my properties that should go into theirs "generic" `Data[] ApplicationDetails` property being both as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDetails
{
    public Data[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string category { get; set; }

    public string attribute { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And those will come from my request as a property named as the attribute should be, i.e. my request will have a property named AIM and I should put that as an the attribute of one of the elements of the Data array, it's value as the element's value and hardcode the category (there are 3 of them).

I couldn't see many advantages (apart for the equally named properties) for using Automapper (or any other it could be) and ended up with a massive static Mapper class that looks this way

```
public static class Mapper
{
    public static Request FromDecisionRequestToZRequest(DecisionRequest request)
    {
        var applicationDetails = new Data[]
        {
            new Data {category = "ID", attribute = "PubID", Value = request.PubID},
            new Data {category = "ID", attribute = "AID", Value = request.AID},
            new Data {category = "APP", attribute = "NID", Value = request.NID},
            new Data {category = "BOOK", attribute = "DupeApps90", Value = request.DupeApps90},
            new Data {category = "BOOK", attribute = "DupeApps30", Value = request.DupeApps30},

            //And many others of each of the three categories

        };

        var address = new Address[]
        {   new Address{
                City = request.City,
                Country = request.Country,
                HouseNumber = request.HouseNumber,
                HouseNumberExtension = request.HouseNumberExtension,
                Street = request.Street,
                ZIP = request.ZIP,
                kind = "MAIN"
            }
        };

        var ret = new Request()
        {
            UserName = request.UserName,
            RequestDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(request.RequestDateTime),
            CompanyRegistrationID = request.CompanyRegistrationID,

            //And many others "direct" mappings

            Addresses = new Addresses { Address = address },
            Phone1 = new Phone1 { type = "1", Value = request.Phone1 },
            Phone2 = new Phone2 { type = "2", Value = request.Phone2 },
            Phone3 = new Phone3 { type = "3", Value = request.Phone3 },
            Email = request.Email,
            Amount = new Amount { Value = request.Amount },

            ApplicationDetails = new ApplicationDetails { Data = applicationDetails }
        };

        return ret;
    }
}
```

How would you tackle this?  To me this static class looks horrible (taking into account that the full one has more than 150 lines but not sure how I could improve it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two extension method , ToApplicationData and ToAddress and will define mapping over there. it will sorten you code and much better readablity. you can break this methods too if you want.

```
 public static class Mapping
    {
        public static Data[] ToApplicationData (this DecisionRequest request)
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new Data {category = "ID", attribute = "PubID", Value = request.PubID},
                new Data {category = "ID", attribute = "AID", Value = request.AID},
                new Data {category = "APP", attribute = "NID", Value = request.NID},
                new Data {category = "BOOK", attribute = "DupeApps90", Value = request.DupeApps90},
                new Data {category = "BOOK", attribute = "DupeApps30", Value = request.DupeApps30}
            };
        }

        public static Address[] ToAddresses(this DecisionRequest request)
        {
            return new Address[]
            {
                new Address
                {
                    City = request.City,
                    Country = request.Country,
                    HouseNumber = request.HouseNumber,
                    HouseNumberExtension = request.HouseNumberExtension,
                    Street = request.Street,
                    ZIP = request.ZIP,
                    kind = "MAIN"
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

This is how I will use this code

```
    public static class Mapper
    {
        public static Request FromDecisionRequestToZRequest(DecisionRequest request)
        {
            var applicationDetails = request.ToData();

            var address = request.ToAddresses();

            var mappedRequest = new Request
            {
                UserName = request.UserName,
                RequestDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(request.RequestDateTime),
                CompanyRegistrationID = request.CompanyRegistrationID,
                Addresses = new Addresses {Address = address},
                Phone1 = new Phone1 {type = "1", Value = request.Phone1},
                Phone2 = new Phone2 {type = "2", Value = request.Phone2},
                Phone3 = new Phone3 {type = "3", Value = request.Phone3},
                Email = request.Email,
                Amount = new Amount {Value = request.Amount},
                ApplicationDetails = new ApplicationDetails {Data = applicationDetails}
            };

            return mappedRequest;
        }
    }
```